# How to overcome the problem. If manager is not available then display manager name 'NA'. If phone number is not available then display as 'NA'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written the query like:

```
1 select resort.resortid,resort.resortname,nvl(manager.name,'NA')MANAGERNAME,
2 nvl(manager.phone,'NA')PHONENO 
3 from 
  resort join manager on resort.managerid=manager.managerid
4 order by resort.resortid;
```

Problem is, I'm not getting the output containing null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular (inner) `join` will only return rows that match the join condition. You're looking for a `left join`:

```sql
SELECT    resort.resortid,
          resort.resortname,
          NVL(manager.name,'NA' ) managername,
          NVL(manager.phone,'NA') phoneno
FROM      resort 
LEFT JOIN manager ON resort.managerid = manager.managerid
ORDER BY  resort.resortid;
```